# EF Core SQLite on Mac and Windows with Publish to Azure

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm looking for an improved solution for cross platform EF Core local dev with stage/production publish to Azure Web/SQL.

**Current Local Solution:**
I have an ASP.NET Core, EF Core, Identity, MVC 6 app with local development on MacOS and Windows using SQLite. SQLite was chosen as I believe it's the only stable db provider for both Mac and Windows. Each time a change is made that requires a database migration we run a script that

1) Deletes the local SQLite database(s) and the existing migration and ContextModelSnapshot files
2) Creates an "initial" migration
3) Updates the database
4) The windows version of the script moves the SQLite databases to the wwwroot directory as we use IIS Express on Windows

Note: Migrations folder is ignored in .gitignore

For local dev the solution is working.

**When I publish to Azure we:**
1) Comment out the services.AddEntityFramework() .AddSQLite() connections and switch to the SQLServer connections
2) Run a script to create a fresh migration (as the migration generated for SQLite doesn't work on Azure SQL)
3) Run a script to delete the database tables on SQL Azure
4) Publish
5) Switch config back to SQLite and continue local dev

I'm hoping someone can suggest a better solution that eliminates most of the manual steps as well as handle the scenario when we have staging/production databases that we want to migrate instead of delete.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue? I find myself in this same situation...except for the script part.

Comment: @NovaDev I haven't come up with a better solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the only correct solution is environment specific methods in Startup.cs [as described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments#startup-conventions).

Basically you create `ConfigureDevelopmentServices()` method and add your environment specific configuration there.